# Center footer in CSS

Tags: html, css, center

I'm very new to coding with html/css. I'm currently working on a project for uni and am stuck with a problem. I want my footer (about me, socials, imprint) to be in the horizontal middle of the page (so just a little bit further on the right). I have tried everything (text-align, justify-content, align-items, ...) - nothing really worked. Has anyone an idea on how to fix it?

I'm thankful for any kind of help :)

Here's my code so far (with a few other problem areas. plus it's probably super messy - sorry!) :

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Baskerville, Helvetica, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1362/2563/products/Kariceramicshandmadepotterybluesixhandceramicdinnerplates_2048x.jpg?v=1591292140);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color: #A5A58D;
}

.header1 {
  height: 90px;
  padding: 80px 0;
  font-size: 68px;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav > ul > li {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="WS 2020 Screendesign.css">
  <title> ALINA'S POTTERY </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-image"></div>


  <div class="header1"> Alina's Pottery </div>

  <nav class="categoryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li class="current"><a href="home.html" title="Home" class="category">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="pottery.html" title="Pottery" class="category">Pottery</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="general.html" title="General" class="subCategory">General</a></li>
          <li><a href="handbuilding.html" title="Hand-Building" class="subCategory">Hand-Building</a></li>
          <li><a href="potterywheel.html" title="Pottery Wheel" class="subCategory">Pottery Wheel</a></li>
          <li><a href="materials.html" title="Materials" class="subCategory">Materials</a></li>
          <li><a href="temperatures.html" title="Temperatures" class="subCategory">Temperatures</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="tutorials.html" title="Tutorials" class="category">Tutorials</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="viewall.html" title="View All" class="subCategory">View All</a></li>
          <li><a href="getstarted.html" title="Get Started" class="subCategory">Get Started</a></li>
          <li><a href="plates.html" title="Plates" class="subCategory">Plates</a></li>
          <li><a href="mugs.html" title="Mugs" class="subCategory">Mugs</a></li>
          <li><a href="bowls.html" title="Bowls" class="subCategory">Bowls</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="shop.html" title="Shop" class="category">Shop</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="products.html" title="Products" class="subCategory">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="contactform.html" title="Contact Form" class="subCategory">Contact Form</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="header2"> Welcome to my pottery portfolio! </div>

  <div class="text1"> I am very passionate about creating my own ceramics. </div>

  <section class="footerContainer">
    <a href="aboutme.html" title="About Me" class="footer">About Me</a>
    <a href="socials.html" title="Socials" class="footer"> Socials</a>
    <a href="imprint.html" title="Imprint" class="footer2">Imprint</a>
  </section>

</body>


<div class="background"></div>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't see the problem. I created a code-snippet and it shows that your footer links are centred horizontally.

Comment: Highly would recommend avoiding `.classes` in your CSS - it makes things very complicated and hard to read. Using built in tags is generally preferred.

Answer (score 0):

try to use flexbox to align the items in the section modifying the css rule like so:

```
.footerContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    bottom: 3%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, the best thing to do is to delete the whole:

```
.footerContainer{
   ...
}
```

The footer will appear centered *(behind the menu dropdown)*, because of the `text-align:center` you put on the `body`.

If at a certain point you would remove that from the `body`, I would also suggest to work with:

```
.footerContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

***And overall feedback:** avoid using `position: fixed/absolute` everywhere, it makes everything more complicated as these elements are removed from the document flow.*

Answer (score 0):

You should try to leverage `display: flex` here, it will solve your issue really fast and it will also adapt easily to further changes. My suggestion here is to change your footer to something like this:

```
<footer class="footer-container">
    <a class="footer-link" href="aboutme.html" title="About Me">About Me</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="socials.html" title="Socials">Socials</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="imprint.html" title="Imprint">Imprint</a> 
</footer>
```

As a side-note, it is better to use `<footer></footer>` instead of `<section></section>` to create your footer, and it also helps with SEO. (Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp)).

And for styling you can simply do this

```
.footer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  /* Change justify-content as you like */
  justify-content: space-around;
}

/* If you don't want or like to use justify-content,
just apply some margins on your links */

.footer-container .footer-link {
  margin: 0 16px; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
.footerContainer {
  bottom: 3%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: oh wow thank you very much! that was one of the combinations I haven't tried - it works!! :)

Comment: I'm glad that I helped

Comment: You're fixing a broken pipe with ducktape here :)

Comment: The solutions above is not a great one. This will appear to solve your issue, but as @isman-f said, it is just a dirty fix.